# Split By Attributes creates no Shapefiles?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, modelbuilder, file-geodatabase, split-by-attribute

I want to create for each polygon of a shapefile a separate shapefile with the [Split By Attributes](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/split-by-attributes.htm) tool.
Input is a polygon shapefile and as split field I choose the ID.
This tool works fine but in the results I cant find any shapefile, only .dbf , .dbf.xml and .cpg.
But why is there no .shp?

As output I tried a workspace and a geodatabase, both didn't worked.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you want shapefiles, your Target Workspace will need to be a folder

Comment: @BERA I tried both: like cou can see in the Folder above there are no shapefiles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you use a Shapefile as an input.

Although this is a type of feature class, the Split by Attributes tool will treat this as a table. To fix this you will need to make sure that your input is in a geodatabase, either by:

- Changing the target destination of the Raster to Polygon tool to a geodatabase
- Adding the [Feature Class to Geodatabase](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/feature-class-to-geodatabase.htm) tool to your model

Answer (score 5):

Your target workspace appears to be a file geodatabase, which means your output will be feature classes. Open the Target GDB in Catalog/ArcMap and you will see the split attributes as single Feature Classes.

The documentation for the tool states the outputs are either feature classes or tables

[image]

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/split-by-attributes.htm

Should you really desire to output Shapefiles, you can add the [Feature Class To Shapefile (Conversion)](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00120000003m000000) tool to your model.

Comment: But when I want to open the target GDB there are only tables and not a single shapefile.

Comment: @David You need to use Catalog to look inside the GDB. Split by Attributes will create multiple feature classes (or shapefiles if your output workspace is a folder), that is what the tool is made to do. You should never get a single feature class or shapefile if you use it the right way

Comment: @BERA Okay I tried to look in the GDB via Arc Catalog but also there are only tables and no shapefile

Comment: Have you checked your input shapefile to make sure it looks correct?