# Running ArcGIS Split By Attributes tool gives error?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, split-by-attribute

While I was doing an exercise for one of my subjects, it was asked to use the "split by attribute" feature on the ModelBuilder in order to get separate shapefiles. The issue is that as soon as I open the tool, wether its inside or outside the ModelBuilder, new or existing project, it shows up an error in the "Input table" section. If I hover my mouse on the error, it wont show any message

[image]

If I try to run it, it won't output me anything

Comment: you may need to be working in a gdb... see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/279596/split-by-attributes-creates-no-shapefiles (not the same question, but their issue may inform yours)

Comment: Have you tried adding your input table to the parameter? It will probably make the red X go away.

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to reproduce your problem, and your graphic does not show your tool dialog in its entirety which might enable me to do a more nuanced test.

When I use the Search window to find and open the Split By Attributes tool using ArcGIS Desktop 10.6 on Windows 7 SP1 it opens with a green dot next to the Input Table as you can see below:

[image]

If you are observing other odd things in your ArcGIS Desktop configuration then, as an expedient, you may want to consider a quick uninstall/reinstall of ArcGIS Desktop rather than trying to troubleshoot something which may be hard to reproduce.

As [you commented](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/298567/running-arcgis-split-by-attributes-tool-gives-error/299148?noredirect=1#comment481631_299148) the uninstall/reinstall resolved this for you.